# How to pull data value slug instead of text in Beautiful Soup web scrape

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to pull the data value slug instead of the rendered website text.

```
<option value="93" data-value-slug="lager-munich-dunkel">Lager - 
Munich Dunkel</option>

#This currently pulls 'Lager Munich Dunkel' instead of 'lager-munich-dunkel'
beer_type = []
    for b in beer_type:
    beer_style = b.select('option')
    beer_row = [i.text for i in beer_style]
    beer_type.append(beer_row)
beer_type
```

I need to pull the data value slug portion of the html so I can use it in the url as `lager-munich-dunkel`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Element attributes are converted to dictionary key/value pairs when using the BeautifulSoup module. So, you can get the value you want like so:

```
# using i.get instead of i[ ] in case there is a default option 
# Which may not have the attribute
beer_row = [i.get('data-value-slug','') for i in beer_style]
```

Comment: exactly what I needed, thanks. I am still quite new to web scraping so I am missing even simple things like this.

Comment: No worries, we've all been there before. You have to start somewhere :)